# Carousel Thumbnail style not auto updating on prev click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got this wonderful pieve of code to auto update my thumbnails on click and on bs.slide function. It works properly when auto updating via the timer interval, clicking the next arrow, or clicking on the respective thumbnail in the carousel.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

var selectorIdx = 1;
var numItems = 12;

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('.carousel-selector').click(function () {
    selectorIdx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(selectorIdx)
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('#myCarousel')
        .find('.carousel-selector')
        .removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
        .end()
        .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');

    if (selectorIdx < (numItems - 1)) {
        selectorIdx++;
    }
    else {
        selectorIdx = 0;
    }
});
```

However the carousel thumbs do not auto update when the prev arrow is clicked, how can this code be updated to reflect that action?

Rough Fiddle, you can see when you hit the prev arrow the thumbs still update going forward instead of backward.

http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/xr8qzxmg/12/

Thank You

Comment: Can't see prev arrow on your fiddle

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan Updated fiddle I forgot to save!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would change your code to select the thumbnail. http://jsfiddle.net/xr8qzxmg/15/

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    selectorIdx = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    $(this)
        .find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
        .end()
        .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');    
});
```

Comment: Excellent @Clayton Leis, Thanks!